# How do you make comments in PureScript?

Tags: purescript

I'd like to know how to make comments in PureScript code.

In Python, the equivalent would be:

```
# Here is a comment
```

Or JavaScript

```
// Another comment
```

What is the equivalent in PureScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [PureScript Language Reference](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Syntax.md), there are single-line comments

```
-- comment
```

and multi-line comments

```
{- comment
   comment line 2
-}
```

Special comments like `-- |` are picked up by documentation tooling.

Comment: A note that `--` compiles to `//` comments in js and `{- ??? -}` compiles to `/* ??? */` in js after trying these out

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do:
`-- some somment`

Comment: yep - that works. One thing to note.. I didn't think it worked at first since comments apparently fail in PSCi. I'm not too surprised as Purescript is still (rapidly) being updated. I went ahead and tried it in a file to see if it was just PSCi that comments don't work in and sure enough when built lines I commented out were ignored. Thank you!